# Remote X Session and Different Window Manager

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop, x11-forwarding

I'm using my HP TouchPad to connect to my Linux box via SSH/X Forwarding, and I'd like to be able to start CTWM when I connect instead of having to start it from the terminal every time (and to keep from having an extra terminal window floating around my desktop). Is there a way to detect a login over SSH/X and fire up CTWM? When I normally interface with the desktop, I want it to continue to use my default Window Manager.

For clarification: The HP TouchPad is hosting the X session full screen, so the window manager is coming from the remote connection as well as the windows.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not possible to do what you are asking. X forwarding use the local window manager. You may try to connect to GDM/XDM/LightDM and open a X session as fullscreen... but i don't know how to specificaly do this through SSH (tunneling rather than X forwarding maybe ?)

An other possibility is to use [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/) that has a good GNU/Linux support, but is not free as in free software (only free as in free beer).

**EDIT to reply the clarified question:**

Add this in your .bash_rc:

```
# test if ssh session
#  && test if DISPLAY is set (X available)
#    && launch window manager.
test -n "$SSH_CLIENT" -o -n "$SSH_TTY" \
   && test -n "${DISPLAY}" \
   &&  window-manager-command &
```

You may also take a look at [XDMCP](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Display_Manager_Control_Protocol) or [FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/) for complete remote sessions.

Comment: added clarification to the original question - the window manager is coming from the remote computer as well